# Grill decal on a sloped white piece

Tags: set-identification

In this bag there is a grill decal on a slope white piece and a minifigure in a black suit with brown hair.  what set would this belong to?[image]

Answer (score 9):

BrickLink calls the part [3297pb051](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3297pb051) Slope 33 3 x 4 with Black and Pearl Dark Gray Vertical Grille Pattern and it's only in [75302](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75302-1) Imperial Shuttle

[image: 75302]

Comment: I initially made a mistake and used 3297px4 Slope 33 3 x 4 with Black and Dark Gray Horizontal Grille Pattern but BrickLink has an entry **This Item is similar in pattern to the following Item(s):** which saved me there.