# I have not had any luck with this part bag - white dish, white plates, Technic

Tags: set-identification

Can someone please help identifying what set it is?

[image: white dish, white plates, Technic]

Comment: The parts in the bag do not match bag 6 of Blue Technic Pin 3L, white Dish 3x3 Inverted and white Wedge Plate 6x3 Left make this set 70709-1 Galactic Titan.

Comment: Note this is the third question you've asked about recently that turned out to be this same set - see [1](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/17195/grill-decal-on-a-sloped-white-piece) [2](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/17198/many-round-white-pieces-and-gray).  You might want to take a closer look at other bags you've got to see if they're also from this set.

Answer (score 6):

Based on 
[6279885: TECHNIC ANGULAR BEAM 4X6](https://brickset.com/parts/6279885/technic-angular-beam-4x6)
, 
[4163986: PLATE 4X6 W. 12 KNOBS](https://brickset.com/parts/4163986/plate-4x6-w-12-knobs)
 and 
[4168072: PLATE 4X12](https://brickset.com/parts/4168072/plate-4x12)
 this must be [75302: Imperial Shuttle](https://brickset.com/sets/75302-1/Imperial-Shuttle)

[image]

This also match up with 2017 copyright mark on the bag, which means your particular copy is produced in 2017 or later as this set is from 2021.